# Slow Website/Webserver/Database Performance - Monitoring, compressing,

Tags: server, apache2, process, webserver

I have an an e-commerce website and it runs very slow.

- What tools are recommended for instant speed increase? For example - I got to know that there is a tool called 'Grunt' that might help with the load time and compress all files in the server. (I know it works with nodejs - don't know if this works on apache2).
  **Are there any other tools that can instantly help?**
- Server process monitoring: General slow loading on my website when using random features in the background - and especially when you're a logged in user. **What is the best best ways to monitor these processes and point them out? What is the best most common tool to get this job done right?** 
  I have found [this](https://www.serverdensity.com/monitor/linux/how-to/) page including a lot of monitoring tools that I just got lost.
- Since it's a shop website - I'm just guessing there are a lot of DB requests. Pretty sure they are heavy - **What is the best way to point out the heaviest DB queries?**